# How to auto resize Snowflake warehouses up/down?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know multi-cluster warehouses can have an autoscaling policy to scale *out*, but is there a way to automate resizing up or down? I have a set of queries that deal with varying sizes of data, which means I sometimes only need a S warehouse, but sometimes need a XL. I don't think Snowflake provides a built-in mechanism to do this, so looking for advice on how to automate this, maybe with a SP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ALTER WAREHOUSE` DDLs to do what you describe and `CALL` a stored proc prior to your queries.

Another alternative is to create a warehouse of each size, then do `USE WAREHOUSE <foo>` prior to your query, which should wake it up, run the query, then suspend once its inactive (although would come with the disadvantage of not being able to reuse locally cached data.)